# How can I control UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp effect direction?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

There are two viewControllers in my project, and one is the main controller. Another is its subview controller used for inserting into the main controller. I set the controller translate animation with `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`, the subView is 'autorotate' left or right, and both the nib filess direction is horizontal.

In my subviewController do the animation `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` is horizontal, but in mainviewController do the same animation the direction is vertical. How can I control the direction?

Comment: This following link may help you. Best of luck>>>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780488

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't provide anything other than curlup, and it is locked to portrait orientation for space reasons.  If you really need it, try building it with CoreAnimation or OpenGL.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer,but i think the direction is control by something like nib's direction.

Comment: This is what happens when you force the modal view to rotate: http://cl.ly/bb8ede6773ba59229136 And in a full screen transition: http://cl.ly/c1bf556b06cf55d99051

Comment: I'm so sorry, i did't see your replay and Thanks very much for your enthusiasm. The problem is not solve

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be a help! :(

Comment: Hi,sir,I think i have find the answer,and now i wanna share it for you.The View now we call it 'view1' loaded by delegate file has never change the page turn direction,but if i we add a subview for view1 the pageturn direction has changed with the correct direction

Comment: Thank your for reading my poor english,and This is my e-mail & MSN,baowuwolf@hotmail ,enjoy talking with you.