# iOS Flip UIImageView 180 degree (not animated)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

How can I flip a `UIImageView` 180 degrees, but NOT animating the flip. I just want when it loads, to show it 180 degrees of the original image.

Comment: This [post][1] will be helpful..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780488/i-want-to-use-animation-to-imageview-using-uianimationtransitioncurl-right-or-le

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` or in the method where you are loading the image, do the following:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.2**

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
```