# UIImage curl from left to right and right to left

Tags: iphone, ios, uianimation

I have this code to curl the page up but I need to curl the page from left to right or right to left. Please help!

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        //[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:imagePage cache:YES];

        //UIView *parent = self.view.superview;
        //[self.view removeFromSuperview];

        //[parent addSubview:moreInfo];
        [imagePage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[collectionOfImages objectAtIndex:countForPages]]];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` and `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight` instead of `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` to flip from left and right. Find the sample [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-FlipImage.html) for your guidance. For curl left and right, check the sample available [here](http://github.com/brow/leaves).

Comment: but I want Curl effect not flip

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625375/iphone-curl-left-and-curl-right-transitions

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929498/iphone-how-to-show-curl-animation-from-left-side

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780488/i-want-to-use-animation-to-imageview-using-uianimationtransitioncurl-right-or-le, http://pastebin.com/mdHWiZGr

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp with one of the other animation types, say for instance UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft or UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight ?